# How to localize App_GlobalResources in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization

i have an ASP.NET website with some "global" resources:

```
\App_GlobalResources
    ContosoFrobberResource.resx
```

This is in addition to the "local" resources associated with each "aspx" file:

```
\App_LocalResources
    Materials.aspx.resx
    Notes.aspx.resx
    OrderHistory.aspx.resx
```

Now i want to localize the site into another locale (e.g. `en`). i create a `resx` file for each "local" resource:

```
\App_LocalResources
    Materials.aspx.en.resx
    Materials.aspx.en-us.resx
    Materials.aspx.en-uk.resx
    Materials.aspx.en-sg.resx
    Notes.aspx.en.resx
    Notes.aspx.en-us.resx
    Notes.aspx.en-uk.resx
    Notes.aspx.en-sg.resx
    OrderHistory.aspx.en.resx
    OrderHistory.aspx.en-us.resx
    OrderHistory.aspx.en-uk.resx
    OrderHistory.aspx.en-sg.resx
```

And that all works fine; the site displays tailored versions of English for

- United States (en-US)
- United Kingdom (en-UK)
- Singapore (en-SG)

as well as a fallback for generic

- English (en)

The problem comes when i try to localize the resources in `App_GlobalResources`:

```
\App_GlobalResources
    ContosoFrobberResource.resx
    ContosoFrobberResource.en-us.resx
```

The web-site crashes with the error:

> CS0101: The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition for 'ContosoFrobberResource'

How do i localize `App_GlobalResources` in an ASP.NET website?

### Bonus Chatter

> ### ContosoFrobberResource.resx
>
> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <root>
>     <data name="ProjectDueDate" xml:space="preserve">
>        <value>Proposal Due Date</value>
>     </data>
>  </root>
> ```

> ### ContosoFrobberResource.qps.resx
>
> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <root>
>     <data name="ProjectDueDate" xml:space="preserve">
>        <value>Prȍposẳl Duɇ Dãtē</value>
>     </data>
>  </root>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer.

ASP.NET doesn't fallback properly to the parent language. If it cannot recognize the file as a "fallback" locale then it fails to parse it, and shows the misleading error.

e.g.

```
ContosoGrobber.resx
ContosoGrobber.en-us.resx
```

works fine. But:

```
ContosoGrobber.resx
ContosoGrobber.en.resx
```

fails when the **"`en`"** portion of the locale string isn't recognized. Changing it to use the full locale name, and avoid the buggy fallback code is the fix. e.g.:

```
ContosoGrobber.qps.resx
```

should become:

```
ContosoGrobber.qps-ploc.resx
```

---

In other words: if a browser is requesting locale `qps-ploc`, **ideally** you could use

```
ContosoGrobber.qps.resx
```

and the local [`qps-ploc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will fallback to `qps`. But because of the bug in ASP.NET it doesn't fallback correctly. This means you cannot *let* it fallback; you have to actually handle all possible locales:

```
ContosoGrobber.qps-ploc.resx
ContosoGrobber.qps-plocm.resx
ContosoGrobber.qps-ploca.resx
```

Comment: This is great. When I first finished reading your post I was...Ohmygod. Microsoft.